# Troubleshooting SQL Count Function

Tags: sql, sql-server

Attempting to execute a SQL query that will determine which airlines and airports have the worst departure delays.

Trying to accomplish the following:

- Determine the average departure delay for airlines at airports. I completed this by using `AVG` function for `Departure_Delay` and the `GROUP BY` clause for `Airline` and `OriginAirportID`
- I want to count how many times an airport appears in the top 1000 of worst departure delays. Tried using the `COUNT` function, but am getting stuck

Side note: I am using SQL Server.

Desired output:

```
OriginAirportID | Airpount_Count
```

Code:

```
SELECT *
FROM
    (SELECT TOP 100 
         AVG(DepDelay) AS Departure_Delay, Carrier, OriginAirportID
     FROM Flights
     GROUP BY Carrier, OriginAirportID
     ORDER BY Departure_Delay DESC) AS Subquery
```

Thank you for the help.

Answer (score 0):

Was able to come up with a solution. As I guessed, it was necessary to use the COUNT function and a Subquery.

**Code Solution:**

```
USE Flights
GO
SELECT COUNT(OriginAirportID) AS Airport_Delay_Count, OriginAirportID
FROM
    (SELECT Top 1000 AVG(DepDelay) AS Departure_Delay, Carrier AS Airline, OriginAirportID
    FROM Flights
    GROUP BY Carrier, OriginAirportID
    ORDER BY Departure_Delay DESC) AS Subquery
GROUP BY OriginAirportID
ORDER BY Airport_Delay_Count DESC
```